# Pingdom uptime calculation formula

Tags: java, pingdom

I am trying to generate uptime report using pingdom apis.

I am using the following formula. But somehow the percentage is not exact as shown in their UI.

```
( ( number_of_days_in_the_months * 86400 ) / 100 ) * uptime_percentage = uptime_in_seconds
```

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: What is your value and how does it differ from the percentage shown in the UI?

Comment: UI shows 99.99 and i am getting it as 99.72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way of doing this.

Use ***summary.outage*** api to get the results and then do the following

```
 SummaryOutage summaryOutage = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, SummaryOutage.class);

        double uptime = 0d;
        double downtime = 0d;
        double unknown = 0d;

        for(SummaryOutage.Summary.State state :summaryOutage.summary.states){
            if(state.status.equals("up")){
                uptime =  uptime + (state.timeto - state.timefrom);
            }else if (state.status.equals("down")){
                downtime  =  downtime + (state.timeto - state.timefrom);
            }else if (state.status.equals("unknown")){
                unknown  =  unknown + (state.timeto - state.timefrom);
            }

        }

        double totalTime = uptime + downtime + unknown;
        if(totalTime > 0) {

            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            String numberAsString = decimalFormat.format(100 *( (uptime + unknown) / totalTime));

            return numberAsString;

        }
```

This works perfect for me. You can enhance the java code as per your expertise.

Hope this is of help to someone.

Comment: Thanks Yahiya! It was very useful for me